# Tab Focus on listview is skipping headers

Tags: c#, listview, focus, uwp-xaml, datatemplate

I have a listview control as below which has header template and item template. On clicking the button which opens this list view, focus first comes to the entire list view.
On hitting tab, focus comes to the first list view item skipping the header.
Anyways I can navigate to headers using up arrow/down arrow keys but the expected behaviour is on hitting tab, focus first comes to the header template

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="DataListView"
    Grid.Row="1" 
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="ListView_ItemClick"
    RightTapped="ListView_RightTapped"
    SelectionMode="None"
    IsTabStop="{x:Bind utilities:XamlExtensions.Invert(ViewModel.IsInitialSetupCompleted), Mode=OneWay}"
    ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelector}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource NoMarginListStyle}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewHeaderItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderContainerStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="today:HeaderGroupViewModel">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="{x:Bind Name}"
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
                        <Button
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Click="MoreOptions_Click"
                            RightTapped="Button_RightTapped"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BrandedChromelessButton}">
                        </Button>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="False"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Any help is appreiciated. I tried using tab index but didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

ListviewItem can be clicked normally and then gets a focus.

So, you could add a ListviewItem to the DataTemplate of HeaderTemplate like the following.

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle >
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListViewItem>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="35" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Button Margin="30,0,0,0" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </ListViewItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    </GroupStyle>
</ListView.GroupStyle>
```

**Update:**

You could set the `IsTabStop` property of ListView and that `button` in HeaderItem to false.
Pleae refer to the following.

```
<ListView 
 ……                  
 IsTabStop="False">
            ……
           <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock ……/>
                            <Button IsTabStop="False"  Grid.Column="1" Margin="30,0,0,0" Content="Click me"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
   ….        
</ListView>
```

Comment: that still doesn't workout. On tab first listview item other than header is getting focused

Comment: @Nisha  I have updated the answer, you could try it.

Comment: By keeping IsTabStop to false for whole list  view, it won't even get focus at first place ryt. IsTabStop property of listview is already binded to one property `IsTabStop="{x:Bind utilities:XamlExtensions.Invert(ViewModel.IsInitialSetupCompleted), Mode=OneWay}"` when it is false, whole list view doesn't get focus

Comment: How many controls does your design interface have, and is there only one ListView? If there is only ListView, it works well.